# Nested For loops counting to 1-100 & 1-1000

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

Hi I am currently in a AP java class in 11th grade. I need specific help on nested for loops counting to 100. I need 2 for loops and said I can't use the numbers 100.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ???; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j <= ???; j++){
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
}
```

I want it to count to 100 from 1 with 2 for loops. And no number 100s. I am going through it step by step the ones I tested, but couldn't figure out completely

more complete answer below:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++){
        System.out.print(i * 10 + j + " ");
    }
}
```

Step 1 (from outer loop): variable i is declared with a value of 0.
Step 2: Test case if i is less than or equal to 9, if true, run body of code in loop. if false, exit loop
Step 3: if outer loop's test case is true, run body of code; declares j to 1, tests if j is less than or equal to 10
step 4: if inner loops' test case is true, run the print command

Comment: You want it to print from 1 to 100, or you want each loop to run 100 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to count from 0 to 99, since you don't want to use 100, So this should do the job.

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++){
            System.out.print(i + "" + j + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Edit 1: If you're interested in printing the range from 1 to 100 instead, You can Parse the string to integer before you print it, and add one to it.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++){
            System.out.print((Integer.parseInt(i + "" + j)+1) + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's an exercise we have to do so it isn't for any purpose. I mean 1-100 for 2 for loops

Comment: @tecimmortal I suppose the second way works for you then?!

Comment: Yes, I took @ScaryWombat 's suggestion for the print statement since it reflects my learning in class already. Thank you guys so much!